# I want to merge all the entries of column and put it in one row each for each column as in the picture

Tags: pandas

I want to merge all the entries of the column and put it in one row each for each column as in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to strings join with [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and convert `Series` to one row `DataFrame` with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df1 = df.astype(str).agg(','.join).to_frame().T
```

Another idea if need only unique values:

```
df2 = df.astype(str).agg(lambda x: ','.join(set(x))).to_frame().T
```

Comment: Okay thanks, let me try and will get back to you

Comment: it works thanks, i have only 13 points and i need to go till 15 to be able to accept it

Comment: @Mohammed Nadeem Do you check link? For accepting please click to empty tick. Thank you.